# How to make a Index That Show Most Viewed This Week

Tags: php, wordpress

This Bellow Code Just Show Most Viewed On The Post , Can u  Make it Into Most Viewed + Just On This week / This month , Not On ALL Time

```
<?php 
    $myposts = array(
        'showposts' => 7,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    );
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query($myposts);
?>
<?php 
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()): 
        $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>
```

This Examples 
[Click The Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndPPE.png)

Comment: I believe you have to a plugin or similar that registers each visit together with date. A plugin such as [Post Views Counter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/) seems to be able to do what you want.

Comment: @hans Westman , Sorry Sir Actually what i need is not showing post view , i need is show a post with most viewed by 1 week , i will put the Examples at my Post

Comment: I don't know how you collect view statistics, but from the looks of your example it seems to be storing only the total number of views, not views per day or week. Some of the larger view counter plugins will store that data, which you can then use in a query to sort on most views in the last week. Are you using a plugin to collect view statistics, and if so, which one?

Comment: if i use view counter plugin have a code , to make :) the post like that Example picture above ?,i will use it if can

Answer (score 1):

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year' => date( 'Y' ),
            'week' => date( 'W' ),
        ),
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
);
```

Try this query , Hope this work for you .

Comment: Thanks For The Answer I will Try It